# E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate

Tags: raspbian, web-server, php, packages

I am using Raspberry pi 2 with raspbian OS. When I try to install Mysql and phpmyadmin to raspberry using following command.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

It shows me following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  php5-mysqlnd

Package mysql-server is a virtual package provided by:
  mysql-server-5.1 5.1.62-1 [Not candidate version]

Package libapache2-mod-auth-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-auth-mysql' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate
```

Many websites and articles suggest to try by updating and upgrading the packages using following command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After executing above commands also I face the same error. 
Some other sites suggested to uninstall and install the package again but that also shows the same error.

Kindly help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Try sudo apt-cache search mysql and see what lists. Mine shows mysql-server-5.5 as well as mysql-server Maybe try the 5.5 Also the lib doesn't show but php5-mysql does

Answer (score 1):

My understanding [from here](http://www.ceus-now.com/ubuntu-13-10-gives-package-libapache2-mod-auth-mysql-has-no-installation-candidate-error/) is that `libapache2-mod-auth-mysql` is dependant on Apache 2.2 packages, whereas the current version of Raspbian runs Apache 2.4. You may wish to uninstall Apache completely, modify your sources.list and then install Apache 2.2, as suggested in [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/512999/rolling-back-to-apache-2-2-on-debian).
Basically, update `/etc/apt/sources.list` to replace `jessie` by `wheezy`, run `sudo apt-get update` and retry to reinstall. When you're done, make sure to undo your changes in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but I am unable to install any package using sudo apt-get command. I tried above link but it also does not clearly guide what I should do. Can you please help me.